# Trigger fails with ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected

Tags: sql, oracle, date, triggers

I am trying to create a trigger on a table (TABLE_1) which detects if a column (ENTERED_DATE) has been changed then update another table (TABLE_2) to set the column (ENTRY_DATE) to the newly changed date on TABLE_1.

Here's what I have:

```
create or replace trigger TRG_NAME
  after insert or update or delete on TABLE_1
  for each row 

  begin 
    if updating then 
        if nvl(:old.ENTERED_DATE, '*') != nvl(:new.ENTERED_DATE, '*') then 
           update TABLE_2 set ENTRY_DATE = :new.ENTERED_DATE where ID = :old.ID; 
        end if; 
    end if; 
end TRG_NAME; 
/
```

The trigger compiles successfully but when I update the column value which is of type date on both tables I get the following error:

`ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected`

I am confused since both fields on both tables are a DATE datatype so why am I getting this error?

Comment: `'*'` isn't a date... it's erroring trying to convert it to one. If you must youe a magic value (and I'm not a fan) then use a date literal.

Comment: @AlexPoole uh *sigh* you're right, I am using that for my check between values, I can just use sysdate right? or any default date for the sake of comparison?

Comment: As long as it's a date that can never appear in either old/new value. I'd prefer to explicitly check for nulls though, even if it more long-winded.

Comment: Just from an efficiency standpoint, as written, you have an `after insert or update` trigger that isn't doing anything for an `insert` so it would be better to declare it as an `after update` trigger.  Even better would be to declare it as an `after update of entered_date` so it only fires when you update the `entered_date`.  Even better would be to only update `table_2` if the value has actually changed.  But best of all from a performance perspective would be to rethink the data model so that this date is only stored in one of the two tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your `nvl`s:

```
if nvl(:old.ENTERED_DATE, '*') != nvl(:new.ENTERED_DATE, '*') then ...
```

Both expressions in `nvl` need to retun the same datatype ; otherwise, if one value is not `null` and the other is, you end up comparing string `'*'` with a date - this operation is not allowed.

I understand that you are looking for a null-wise comparison ; in standard SQL we would use operator `IS DISTINCT FROM` - but Oracle does not supports it.

If you have a date that you know for sure never appears in your data, you can do:

```
nvl(:old.ENTERED_DATE, date '1990-01-01') != nvl(:new.ENTERED_DATE, date '1990-01-01')
```

Otherwise you need to enumerate the logical combinations :

```
 :old.ENTERED_DATE != :new.ENTERED_DATE
 or (:old.ENTERED_DATE is null and :new.ENTERED_DATE is not null)
 or (:new.ENTERED_DATE is null and :old.ENTERED_DATE is not null)
```

Comment: thank you so much for the detailed explanation, makes more sense now.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use [LNNVL](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/LNNVL.html#GUID-FBCCE9B1-614E-45FA-8EE1-DFAA4F936867) in combination with `COALESCE`:

```
update TABLE_2 set ENTRY_DATE = :new.ENTERED_DATE 
where ID = :old.ID
   and LNNVL(:old.ENTERED_DATE = :new.ENTERED_DATE) 
   and coalesce(:old.ENTERED_DATE, :new.ENTERED_DATE) is not null;
```